# getline(cin, string) not working EVEN WITH cin.ignore()

Tags: c++, console, std, iostream, getline

There are several questions on this site referring to `getline` not working, the apparent solution is that there are remaining newline characters in the buffer that need to be cleared, supposedly with `cin.ignore()`.  I've tried so many variations of this and nothing seems to work, all I'm trying to do is simple console input and `cin >> string` isn't an option because the string might have spaces.

Here is my code.

```
void prompt(std::string * str)
{
    cout << "> ";

    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore(256, '\r');
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');
    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();

    std::string tmp;
    getline(cin, tmp);

    cin.sync();
    cin.get();
    cin.ignore(256, '\r');
    cin.ignore(256, '\n');

    *str = tmp;
}
```

As you can see I've tried all sorts of things.  It still skips right over `getline(cin,tmp)` and appears to set `str` to an empty string.  Please help.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions with the C tag

Comment: Try removing all the `ignore()` commands and use `std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, tmp);` instead. The `>> std::ws` skips all whitespace (including end of lines).

Comment: I don't see any error-checking.  Do `if (!cin) { cout << "Something set the failbit." << endl; }`

Comment: @BenVoigt I totally neglected to do that, and it appears the failbit is set.  What should I do?

Comment: @Jake: Find out how far back in your code the failbit got set, and fix it.  If it was supposed to be set (e.g. handling malformed input), then use `cin.clear()` to reset the failbit and try another operation.

Answer (score 2):

Once any formatted extraction has failed, the failbit will be set on your stream, and future operations will do nothing at all.  This is somewhat convenient because you can handle errors in groups, instead of checking after every single operation.  But once you detect an error, you need to reset the failbit in order to try something different.  The command to do that is pretty simple:

```
cin.reset();
```

Comment: It looks like the `getline` call is setting the failbit

Comment: @Jake: So right before the `getline`, `if (cin) cout << "Everything is ok" << endl;` and after the getline, `if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;` both print?  Are you redirecting input from a file?  `getline` is not very picky about the input format, I can't think what can cause it to fail besides the stream ending.

Comment: yeah, those both print, and I'm not sure what you mean but I'm not doing anything (intentionally) with files, just trying to read console input really :\

Answer (score 0):

Passing variables using pointers is discouraged. If you want to get the value back from the function references `&` are recomended.

I don't know the context you are calling `prompt()` in but here is a suggestion for implementing `prompt()` that may work better for you.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// return bool so you know if it failed or not
bool prompt(std::string& s) // use reference
{
    std::cout << "> ";
    return std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, s);
 }

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::string s;

    do
    {
        if(!prompt(s)) // always check the imput
            break;

        // process the string (reverse it for example...)
        std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());
        std::cout << "reversed: " << s << '\n';

        std::cout << "Another go? [y/n]: ";
    }
    while(std::cin.get(c) && std::tolower(c) == 'y');
}
```