# std::getline(std::cin) setting failbit

Tags: c++, c++11

I have no clue what's going on and I've tried all sorts of things with `cin`, including ignore with and without parameters and sync and all sorts of things.  All I'm trying to do is `getline(cin, str)`.  I'm on visual studio express 2013 if that helps anything.

Here's my code:

```
bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;
    pause();
    return true;
}
```

*Edit:  Removed a `cin.ignore` and a `cin.sync`.  Error still happens*

The program as of now outputs "everything is ok" and "cin is failed".  No pause except for after the "cin is failed" bit.

Any ideas?  Thank you very much.

Comment: What's the purpose of `cin.sync();`?

Comment: @jrok I'm not sure to be perfectly honest.  I was just recommended to try it and threw it in here to illustrate I've tried about everything that's been thrown at me.

Comment: Also, if `cin.ignore(256,'\r˙);` has got less than 256 characters avaliable, it'll block and wait for input. I've got to ask - what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @MarcoA. I'm just trying to read the console.  I did the `cin.ignore` because apparently there can still be whitespace left in the buffer that causes `getline` to fail.

Comment: That's misinformation. `getline` will not fail because of whitespace.

Comment: @jrok the same happens when I take it out.  I'm just making a function for now to print out stuff to the console and then take an input from the console.

Comment: @Niall That's what I figured to be honest, I have no clue what's going on nor how to reproduce it

Comment: This won't help you much, but the code works on a Linux box with g++. Maybe you need to supply some special build options on Windows to have std::cin 'wired up' to stdin and command.com. Maybe there's a "console app" project type you need to use?

Comment: @Weston didn't think of that, I bet that has something to do with it.  It's built in as a static library and linked to a blank project so... I'll figure out something

Comment: have you tried using cin's operator>>? as in 'std::cin >> str;'

Comment: There seems to a problem with the input stream (std::cin). Do you compile your program in console mode/subsystem? Also did you try running your program outside of visual studio?

Comment: Why you use both `cin` and `std::cin`? Are you `using namespace std` if not, check again where `cin` (without *std::*) come from.

Comment: @NicolasHolthaus That fails too.  For the record I'd want to stray away from that as that terminates at any whitespace as opposed to the enter key

Comment: @kyflare I haven't, I will when I get home.  I don't know if it's in "console mode", does that mean a console project?  Clearly I don't know hah

Comment: @RaydelMiranda I am `using namespace std`, not sure why, just habit i suppose

Comment: [Can't reproduce](http://ideone.com/oOe9WP), the problem does not lie with your program

Comment: I'm missing a [short, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here.

Comment: Consider posting a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: this occurs when some other process terminates your running program.

Comment: Even compiling this code as a separate library, and then linking it to a blank program in VS still worked. I even tried setting the library subsystem to both console and native, both still worked. My best guess is that cin is getting set to a bogus ostream at some point. It's still considered valid, until it's used. Can we see the rest of the code for the library?

Comment: @Weston I feel you deserve the bounty for this as your comment was closest to the answer (see what I posted).  Would it be viable for you to post an answer or something so I can award you the bounty?  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was going on.  Incredibly stupid of me, I completely forgot to realize how I allocated the console in the first place.  In my main function:

```
if (AllocConsole())
{
    freopen("CONOUT$", "wt", stdout);
    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);
}
```

I used this snippet floating around the internet forever.  However it didn't occur to me that the input stream had yet to be linked to the console.  I added this line:

`freopen("CONIN$", "rt", stdin);`

And that did the trick seemingly.

Answer (score 3):

I compiled the following code with Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 Update 3. The pause(); statement is commented out since I do not know what it is.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;
    // pause();
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string strIn;
    prompt(strIn);
    cout << "Input: " << strIn << endl;
}
```

When run it, the output is

```
>
Everything is ok
Input Test.
Input: Input Test.
```

I do not see the failbit problem. Maybe something is wrong with the Visual Studio Express 2013?

### From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

> failbit:   The input obtained could not be interpreted as a valid textual
>   representation of an object of this type. In this case, distr
>   preserves the parameters and internal data it had before the call.
>   Notice that some eofbit cases will also set failbit.

If enter Ctrl+Z as the input, "cin is failed" does show up:

```
>
Everything is ok
^Z
cin is failed
Input:
```

Comment: That's the same answer I posted some time ago, it seems that for whatever reason doesn't please OP.

Comment: Not a problem with express, this code runs fine in my express install.

Answer (score 0):

It is true that

```
if(cin) 
  std::cout "everything is okay";
```

would not print the statement if `cin` has the `fail` or `bad` bit set, but not if it has the `eof` [bit set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/operator_bool/):

```
bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl; // Will be printed
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl; // Will be printed
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    std::string obj;
    std::cin.setstate(std::ios::eofbit); // Simulate an eof/Ctrl^Z on Win read
    prompt(obj);
}
```

<kbd>[Reproducer](http://ideone.com/sX6TpJ)</kbd>

a previous operation might have left it set, this was also discussed in [one of your previous topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185641/getlinecin-string-not-working-even-with-cin-ignore).

To ensure `cin` is in a valid state you should first unset its state bits with `cin.clear();`

```
bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cin.clear(); // Reset state bits
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;
    return true;
}
```

if your code still happens to fail, make sure you're actually reading a valid textual input and avoid reading [invalid characters](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/03/16/90448.aspx).

Comment: I copied and pasted that verbatim and the code is still failing.  I have no clue where an invalid character would come into the console as nothing can even be entered, it just fails immediately

Comment: At this point you should probably post the full code. I see no other way to deal with that error.

Comment: Please also check console codepage (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682064(v=vs.85).aspx) by running "chcp".  I got "Active code page: 437".

Comment: That's true @Jake you should also check that

Comment: @Garland same thing here.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this problem on eclipse:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


using namespace std;

bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    string strIn;
    prompt(strIn);
    cout << "Input: " << strIn << endl;
}
```

Now you will get the output:

```
> 
Everything is ok
cin is failed
Input:
```

whenever you terminate your running program on eclipse. This means that some other process might be terminating your running program.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to imitate these results through a few different methods, all of which involve some odd things that redefine cin or the specifically look to set cin to an odd state. The following code will generate this issue:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool prompt(std::string &str)
{
    cout << "> ";
    if (cin) cout << endl << "Everything is ok" << endl;
    std::getline(std::cin, str);
    if (!cin) cout << "cin is failed" << endl;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    cin.setstate(ios::eofbit);
    string test;
    prompt(test);
}
```

That code generates the output:

```
>
Everything is ok
cin is failed
```

This code set the eof flag for cin, which doesn't cause it to be failed so the check for cin returns true, but any attempt to read it immediately fails. The other method involves changing the definition of cin within  (or in my case, I copied it and then modified it and included the copy). These are the only ways I was able to figure out to produce the output that your function has in visual studio 2013.